# UI Automation - WinForms button handler not triggering

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

Using the Microsoft UI Automation framework, I've setup an example where if I press a hotkey, it registers an event handler for the AutomationElement under the cursor (typically a button).

However when I press the button, the event handler doesn't get called.

I've used [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/subscribe-to-ui-automation-events) from the official docs to subscribe to the event.

Interestingly, the code below works for Win32 apps (tested with Notepad++) but not for WinForms (.NET) apps. Any idea how to get this working for a target .NET app?

Code:

```
public partial class FormAuto : Form
{
    //...

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.F8)
        {
            Thread trd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadTask));
            trd.IsBackground = true;
            trd.Start();
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    private void ThreadTask()
    {
        System.Windows.Point point = new System.Windows.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
        AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromPoint(point);

        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(InvokePattern.InvokedEvent, element, 
            TreeScope.Element, new AutomationEventHandler(OnUIAutomationEvent));
       
        while(true)
            Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    private void OnUIAutomationEvent(object src, AutomationEventArgs e)
    {
        AutomationElement sourceElement = src as AutomationElement; //doesn't get called
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the element you target under the cursor is a button and/or supports the invoke pattern? Do you have a complete reproducing project?

Comment: @SimonMourier I think it does, because I ca do this: `((InvokePattern)element.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern)).Invoke();`. You can find the project and a test app [here](https://github.com/mihaifm/playground/files/9077723/uiautomation.zip)

Comment: If the WinForms app is yours (you can edit it), set the Button's `FlatStyle` to `FlatStyle.System`

Comment: As a note, you can get Button state changes with `SetWinEventHook()`, registering `EVENT_OBJECT_STATECHANGE`

Comment: I've tried numerous combinations (.NET Core, x64 vs x86, from window's subtree, etc.) using a simple console app: https://pastebin.com/raw/gHEsbhkF and it never works with Winforms. It does work fine with WPF... Since it doesn't work with .NET Core you could ask Microsoft as they still support and maintain it. Since it's using a Win32 textbox, maybe this doesn't support it. Note how it should be designed for an implementor is a bit obscure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-implementinginvoke#implementation-guidelines-and-conventions

Comment: @SimonMourier I've verified that setting the Button's `FlatStyle` to `System` doesn't work anymore in .Net 6+ (while it works in .Net Framework). But that's not weird if you look at what there's now in the [OnClick override](https://source.dot.net/#System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/Button.cs,236): the event raised is PropertyChanged, set to NameProperty (so `30005` instead of `20009` - `Invoke_InvokedEventId`). So, adding an `AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler` specifying `AutomationElement.NameProperty`, when you click the Button the event is raised. This needs to be fixed, IMO